# Local variable on the stack not getting deleted when out of scope

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>

int* retPointer()
{
    int x=10; //same as auto int x =10;
    return &x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout<<"x="<<*retPointer()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the example above I am returning a pointer that points to a local variable to stack. When I print the value pointed by this pointer in the man() then I should get a seg-fault. The variable x should go out of scope when I return from function retPointer(). So when try to access the value in main() should I not get a segmentation fault? Am I missing something here?

Output is = x=10

Comment: Welcome to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Well, the stackframe is lost, but the memory still exists after the function terminates, but actually it shouldn't happen...

Comment: Where does the standard say you should get a seg-fault?

Comment: look at [this code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2LgTCL$2) to ensure, that you're wrong

Comment: borisbn- I have copied and pasted your code. I still get Hi x=10. I understood that its a undefined behavior. I am using MinGW 64 bit compiler in windows.

Answer (score 5):

The `x` object *does* go out of scope when returning from `retPointer()`, and dereferencing a pointer to an object whose lifetime has expired is **Undefined Behavior**.

A program having Undefined Behavior means that *anything* could happen, including a crash, behaving as if nothing happened (like `*retPointer()` returning a normal value such as `10`), or formatting your hard drive.

Although the last option is quite unlikely, you definitely do **not** want to have Undefined Behavior in your program. Do not ever return pointers or references to local objects with automatic storage.

Answer (score 0):

> When I print the value pointed by this pointer in the man() then I should get a seg-fault.

You should? Where in the spec does it say this will happen?

You're invoking undefined behaviour. *Anything* could happen.